# How can I delete a symbolic link in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-7, symbolic-link

I created a symlink using `mklink`.  Now I need to change it but I can't figure out how to delete it so I can recreate it correctly.

Answer (score 718, accepted):

**Be very careful.**

If you have a symbolic link that is a directory (made with `mklink /d`) then using [`del`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del) will delete all of the files in the target directory (the directory that the link points to), rather than just the link.

**SOLUTION:** [`rmdir`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rmdir) on the other hand will only delete the directory link, not what the link points to.

Comment: Having just accidentally done this (deleted the complete contents of the target folder), this an important tip.

Comment: This answer is not entirely accurate. `Del` deletes files, not folders. Therefore, you would not use `del` to delete the link.

Comment: But don't use `rmdir` in PowerShell. Wrap it in `cmd` first. See my answer below...

Comment: How about if i delete it through windows explorer????

Comment: Now you tell me!  Doh!

Comment: When I tried rmdir for a sym link I'd created it gave me an error.  I could delete the shortcut in Win Explorer though and it didn't affect the target.  This was for a link I created using mklink w/o any flags.  When I use the \D flag to create the link then I think rmdir might work better (although I didn't try it).

Comment: I was concerned about rmdir on a dir that isn't a SYMLINKD but rmdir *will* offer a warning if it's a directory that's not empty.

Comment: You can also use `rm` command in Window bash shell.

Comment: I don't get at which moment the devs considered it logical to delete files behind a link when deleting the link. After the 5th or  6th beer? Or perhaps after the mushrooms...

Comment: @RomainVincent, for backward compatibility reasons, a "directory link" (i.e. SYMLINKD) is actually a directory that's also a link (i.e. reparse point). CMD doesn't special case that it's a link. However, it does prompt with an "Are you sure (Y/N)?" warning that it's about to delete "<link path>\\*". I agree that it would be better to special case the behavior for directory links. The API itself special cases them, e.g. `RemoveDirectory` will remove a directory link even though the target directory isn't empty, but trying the same on the link target directly would fail.

Comment: I guess Windows is not good at symbolic links and it's safer not to use them at all there.

Comment: @Simon Gillbee Didn't it ask you Y/N?

Comment: If you try to delete a non-empty directory which is *not* a symbolic link using `rmdir`, it will fail as the directory is not empty. If you use the same command on symbolic link to a non-empty directory it will succeed.

Comment: I did this, and now I get the drive with a question mark on it, still unable to use the drive letter for a network drive.

Comment: If you're not sure if a Windows symlink is to a file or to a directory, and you're writing a batch script to delete and recreate some symlinks, [the solution I've come to, and documented here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76561131/4561887) is to always run `rmdir my_symlink` first, followed by `del my_symlink`, _not_ the other way around! This way, if it's a symlink to a directory, the symlink gets safely deleted without touching the target dir, and `del` safely fails, and if it's a symlink to a file, `rmdir` safely fails, and `del` safely deletes it. _Order matters._ Answer upvoted.

Answer (score 124):

To remove directory symbolic links created with `mklink /d` it is safe to delete the symbolic link in windows explorer.

Comment: +1 for telling people it is save to delete symbolic link through Windows Explorer.

Comment: It is correct. I do it all the time. Just tested it again right now.

Comment: This just worked for me as well. i deleted the link not the source folder that was linked to. perhaps that the catch.

Comment: It is safe to just delete it with Rightclick -> Delete. This does NOT delete the linked folder.

Comment: mklink /d Didn't work for me on Windows 7.. I may have been using an old version though

Comment: this works but I was trying to move a parent folder so beware that the symlink will still hold a lock from the recycle bin. Using `SHIFT`+`DEL` is useful to bypass the bin.

Answer (score 56):

For a symlink to a file, use `del`. For a symlink to a directory made with `mklink /d`, use `rmdir`.

Comment: Warning: "del" will delete the file and not just the link.

Comment: Warning from @Tristan is not correct, this answer is accurate. Tested on windows 7.

Comment: In Windows 7 SP1 (64-bit), a symbolic link that points to either a file (e.g. created using MKLINK) or to a directory (MKLINK /D) can be deleted in Windows Explorer, using the ordinary Windows GUI 'delete' option, _without_ deleting the target. Even a *JUNCTION* (e.g. created using the MKLINK /J command), if deleted in Explorer, will not delete the target directory nor its contents. If not empty, the target directory cannot even be deleted using the command DEL _junction_ at the command prompt. Tested today.

Comment: On Windows Server 2012, this removed the directory contents that my symlink was pointed to...

Comment: You should warn people not to `rmdir` links from Powershell!

Answer (score 32):

In Powershell, don't use `rmdir`! Use `cmd /c rmdir .\Target` instead. I tested this myself and confirmed it here: http://kristofmattei.be/2012/12/15/powershell-remove-item-and-symbolic-links/

Comment: That blog confuses the meaning of "Target", which is the actual directory the link points to, and which folks generally wish to avoid deleting whilst removing the link.

Comment: [`rmdir` is an internal command of cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html), thus obviously to call it from other shells you'll need `cmd /c` or `cmd /k`.  `rmdir` in PowerShell is just an alias to `Remove-Item`

Comment: To add to the confusion, `del` is also an alias to `Remove-Item` in PowerShell. So, while `del` in cmd recursively deletes files, `del` in PowerShell only removes the link.

Answer (score 28):

There is another solution tested by me and safe to use.
just add to the real folder _ (example: foo become foo_)
then simply delete your symbolik link, then remove _ from your true folder.

Comment: yeah, this is 100% safest solution after you know that powershell does not give a s**t about rmdir

Comment: This is a clever precaution. +1

Comment: Warning: I don't think this MIGHT not work on Win10 since it's fixing shortcuts upon renaming. (At least classic Shortcuts) Not tested though.

Comment: I did this just in case. After I renamed the target folder, the symbolink link failed when I tried to access it, so I could delete it without worrying.

Answer (score 24):

mklink cannot be used to delete symbolic links. To remove a symbolic link, simply delete them as if you’re removing a normal file. For example, to delete the foo symbolic link created above, enter the following command:

If the link is a hard link to a directory:

```
C:\test>rmdir foo
```

or else, IF the link points to a file (as opposed to a dir)

```
C:\test>del foo
```

Source: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/22/create-symbolic-links-hard-links-and-directory-junctions-in-vista-with-mklink/

Comment: Just make sure you don't delete it with `del /S` or Explorer.

Comment: See eddyq's answer below because using del for a link made to a directory won't work and instead will attempt to delete teh contents of the folder.

Comment: Hardlinks to directories don't exist.  I think you meant to say symlink.

Answer (score 2):

I've installed this [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). With this, you have 2 methods.

## METHOD 1

Create it using the context menu as shown and deleting via file explorer.

Test with a folder like `C:\Windows\Logs` as shown or similar.
I'm just creating a directory of all the possible locations of temp files to delete and I wanted a central folder where I could monitor the size of them via symbolic links.

***Please note:** The screen going white is just the [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).*

[image: delete from explorer method]

## METHOD 2

The safest way [undocumented here AFAIK](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html).

On the created symbolic link (*in steps shown above*), right-click on it this time and click properties then go to the <kbd>Link Properties</kbd> tab.

**Note:** This shell extension added this tab.

Before I go on, lots more info can be [found here](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html), also, on the homepage are the [x64 and 32bit versions](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#contact).

So, to continue, here you can add anything to the target field as long as it's **different** to the original target.

---

1. Here's a before with the target as `C:\Windows\Logs`
   [image: target before]
2. Here's an after with the target as `C:\Windows\Logs_`, **notice** the extra `_` at the end.

   [image: target after]
3. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>
4. You can check this again by going over the same 1-3 steps above to ensure that has stuck, this time you will get an error message when you click on the <kbd>Link Properties</kbd> tab so the link is now broken.
5. It is now safe(r) to delete the symbolic link than method 1 IMHO.

---

But! Both methods work here so it's entirely up to the user's choice. I like the properties method which I happily stumbled upon, so you're 100% sure the link is broken by using **step 4** above.

Here's a gif of me creating a symbolic link by right mouse button dragging a folder to another and choosing the option to create a symbolic link in the sub-menu.

To delete, just follow the  1-5 steps above of method 2 or follow method 1.

**How to create and delete a symbolic link using the properties method**

***Please note:** The screen going white is just the [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).*

[image: gif on how to create and delete syn links using the properties method]

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Windows 10), after creating the symbolic link using

```
MKLINK /D "C:\Users\username\Dropbox\MyProject" "C:\SourceProject"
```

and **deleting via delete using the file explorer or keyboard delete key** **also deletes the original directory**.

What you should do is to remove the link via command prompt.

```
C:\Users\username\Dropbox>rd /s MyProject
```

For details about the rd command: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd

Comment: Only this worked. Add `/Q` to have no prompt

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to move the folder (at which the symbolic link is pointing) to another place (to parent folder) and then delete the symbolic link. No files will be harmed!

Answer (score 1):

Create Windows 10 directory symbolic link:

```
MKLINK /D "C:\Users\andronoid\Program Files" C:\Users\andronoid\AppData\Local
```

Delete Windows 10 directory symbolic link:

- [eddyq's `RMDIR` solution](https://superuser.com/a/306618/999367) from an elevated command prompt **didn't work** for me: *Access is denied.*
- [ddelrio1986's *Windows Explorer* solution](https://superuser.com/a/377867/999367) **did work** (the link target was untouched)

Answer (score 1):

There is one odd case not handled by any of the excellent answers here.  That is when someone creates a file symbolic link to a folder (directory).  This typically happens when someone has made a little boo-boo and forgot to include the "/D" option with `mklink`.

Not that I have ever done that. No, never.  ;)

In this rare case, using the `del` command will successfully remove the symlink.  And more sleep will help prevent this rare breed of symlink in the first place.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/178014/348859

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm referring to a file symlink to a directory.  For example, created accidentally with: `mklink c:\windows`

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted the symbolic link folder on my server.

1)I've deleted the sub files and folders in the symbolic link.

****Get-ChildItem D:\test\link\* -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse****

2)I've deleted the target folders.(this command similuare with chttps://superuser.com/a/684697/1749990).

**Get-ChildItem "D:\test\link" | Get-Item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Target | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse**

3)Finally, I've deleted the link folders successfully.

**cmd /c rmdir (Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\test\link" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to delete executable links that vim put on my windows machine Desktop, pressing windows, finding Terminal, right clicking the app and choosing **Run as Administrator**

Then, using Powershell, you navigate to the location, here are some helpful locations:

```
C:\Users\Public\Desktop

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\[PROGRAM FOLDER]
```

Then when you find the shortcuts:

```
rm desiredfile.lnk
```