# "Renaming" Dropbox (Personal) folder as a plain Dropbox folder? Looking for smylink command on all OS

Tags: linux, windows, macos, dropbox, symbolic-link

Dropbox's desktop client will create two separate Dropbox folders if one uses a linked personal account with an enterprise account (in my case, this is a Dropbox account within an institution's own Dropbox domain).
Yet, depending on how and when the two Dropbox accounts are linked, the following variants of "Dropbox folder" can be produced in the home directory:

1. Version 1:

   - `~/Dropbox (personal)`
   - `~/Dropbox`, where this is symlinked to `~/Dropbox (Name of the Institution)`
2. Version 2:

   - `~/Dropbox (personal)`
   - `~/Dropbox (Name of the Institution)`
3. Version 3:

   - `~/Dropbox`
   - `~/Dropbox (Name of the Institution)`

Dropbox has no interest in fixing its desktop client that throws random names, and the best way is to symlink a local `~/Dropbox` folder to its local variants. Per my use case, I am only interested in appointing one of the Dropbox folder to be `~/Dropbox`.

Here is what works for Windows using Command Prompt (Admin mode), where all my local scripts sourcing from `~/Dropbox` (as linked below) are working nicely.

```
mklink /D c:\Users\username\Dropbox "c:\Users\username\Dropbox (Name of the institution)"
```

---

**Edit**: to *remove* such symlink, use `rmdir Dropbox` in Command Prompt again. As explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/595197/361600), `rmdir` is a command specific to the Command Prompt.

For Powershell, `rmdir` is an alias for something else and may warn about

> The item at `C:\Users\username\Dropbox\` has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?"

No one need to bother with any of these details, as `rmdir Dropbox` works out of the box in Command Prompt.

---

Please advise the proper symlink commands for other OS, in particular:

- WSL-Windows
- Linux
- Mac

Comment: It should be `ln` for all three ...

Comment: What flag should I use? `-d` for hard link or `-s` for symbolic link?